# Cannot get errors from input validation in Angular 6

Tags: angular, validation, forms

I have a form which is supposed to check if what the user typed is long enough, then add an alert if it isn't. There are other possible validation errors that I may have to check in the future, but the first one (`minlength`) is not working.

The code for the form is as follows:

```
      <form *ngIf="editingName" #nameForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveName()">

        <input name="name-input" *ngIf="editingName" class="name-edit" required minlength="3" maxlength="30"  
               [(ngModel)]="editedName" placeholder="{{editedName}}" (change)="updateForm()">

        <button [disabled]="!nameForm.form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save Name</button>

        <div *ngIf="!nameForm.form.valid && name-input.errors.minlength" class="alert">
          Name must have at least 3 letters!
        </div>

      </form>
```

I used Angular's own [guide](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) section on input validation as a base.

However, when I type in the form, the alert does not trigger and I get multiple instances of an error that says

> ERROR TypeError: "_co.input is undefined"

At first I thought the problem might be with the hyphen in `title-edit`, but changing to a name without hyphen or any special characters resulted in the same problem.

Note: I had found this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754970/typeerror-co-nome-is-undefined-in-angular5-form-validation?rq=1) which seems similar, but they are defining some of their form in the typescript side. Since my form only has a single input and a button, this seems overkill and I want to set it up on the .html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from how you access the errors - `!nameForm.form.valid && name-input.errors.minlength`. The syntax `name-input` is not valid, and is not properly wired to your input element.

---

I suspect this is being interpreted as `name - input.errors.minlength`, hence the error about "input is undefined", but that's beside the point.

---

To reference this field in a binding (or the component TypeScript), you need to tell Angular to store it off into a variable - just like you do with `nameForm`.

```
<form *ngIf="editingName" #nameForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveName()">
    <input #nameInput="ngModel" name="name-input" *ngIf="editingName" class="name-edit" required minlength="3" maxlength="30"  
           [(ngModel)]="editedName" placeholder="{{editedName}}" (change)="updateForm()">

    <button [disabled]="!nameForm.form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save Name</button>

    <div *ngIf="!nameForm.form.valid && nameInput.errors.minlength" class="alert">
      Name must have at least 3 letters!
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked. I did change the name to stop using that pesky hyphen too. 
Thank you.